# SCSS combine variables or create new one with mixin

Tags: variables, sass

These are some color vars

```
$orangeTp            :#ec6532;
$orangeBt            :#f58795;
$orangeNv            :#ea6740;
```

This is my gradient mixin

```
@mixin gradient-bg($color1,$color2){
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        from($color1),
        to($color2)
    );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top center;
}
```

I use them like :

```
.bg-orange {
    @include gradient-bg($orangeTp,$orangeBt); 
}
```

and this is the new mixin I try to use and fail

```
@mixin themes($themecolor) {
    @include gradient-bg(#{$themecolor}+Tp,#{$themecolor}+Bt);
    a {
        color: #{$themecolor}+Nv;
        &:hover {
            color: #{$themecolor}+Tp;
        }
    }
}
```

What I try to accomplish is to crate the variable (`$orangeTp` or `$orangeBt`) by using a new variable (`$themecolor`) so that I can just write:

```
.bg-orange {
    @include themes('$orange');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use interpolation to create dynamic variables, but maps can help you to resolve your problem:

```
$colors: (
  orangeTp:#ec6532,
  orangeBt:#f58795,
  orangeNv:#ea6740
);

@mixin gradient-bg($color1,$color2){
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        from($color1),
        to($color2)
    );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top center;
}

@mixin themes($themecolor) {
    @include gradient-bg(map-get($colors, $themecolor#{Nv}), map-get($colors, $themecolor#{Bt}));
    a {
        color: map-get($colors, $themecolor#{Nv});
        &:hover {
            color: map-get($colors, $themecolor#{Tp});
        }
    }
}

.bg-orange {
    @include themes(orange);
}
```

I created a Sassmeister for you: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/e9cf096735ec51b2243a634ae19b9946

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @ReSedano

Comment: You're welcome. If this aswer resolve your problem, please accept it so you can sign as accepted also for the other users. Thank you :)